# How-to Test if Umbraco property is empty

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'm can't figure out how to test if a non-mandatory property is empty in my umbraco site, and currently my pages cause an XSLT parsing error if said property is empty. My current code is simple:

```
<xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(sectionImage, 0)" />
<xsl:if test="$media"> <!-- or $media != null -->
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="$media/umbracoFile" />
    <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$url" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

I'm running Umbraco v6.0.6 and I've using the error checking solution as provided on the umbraco wiki, at http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getmedia

When I tried a similar style logic in C# I found that the test variable, $media, would have a value such as "umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Property." This filler content would wrongly bypass the if test, and then cause a break down.

This is happening on a variety of data types; media files, text strings, integers, etc.

Thank you for your time reading my post.

Answer (score 1):

umbraco.library:GetMedia cannot return null, you may get an error back if no media was matched, in example

```
<error>No media is maching '123123'</error>
```

The thing is that your code works but you dont close the <xsl:attribute name="src"> as you should

```
<xsl:attribute name="src">
  <xsl:value-of select="$url" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

If you for some reason really like to ensure that there is an image in there you should write a "test" and count values in the nodeTypeAlias

```
<xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(sectionImage, 0)" />
<xsl:if test="count($media[@nodeTypeAlias='Image']) > 0">
  <xsl:variable name="url" select="$media/umbracoFile" />
  <xsl:element name="img">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
      <xsl:value-of select="$url" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

The xpath becomes a bit "odd" since you work with zero depth selection, if you fetch media with a greater depth you must adjust the count a bit

```
<xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(sectionImage, 0)" />
<xsl:if test="count($media/*[@nodeTypeAlias='Image']) > 0">
  ...
</xsl:if>
```

To test if a folder was selected simply check for folder instead

```
<xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(sectionImage, 0)" />
<xsl:if test="count($media[@nodeTypeAlias='Folder']) > 0">
  ...
</xsl:if>
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for all the help I apologize for missing the attribute closing, that was my own typing error.
I'm very new to XSLT, and poking around further what I'm finding is the initial variable assign is the problem. The XML of sectionImage is just <sectionImage /> and I would like to test if this is null before assigning any values, but still problems. I'm trying in C# to say var sectionImage = umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().GetProperty("sectionImage") and then test if sectionImage != null, but GetProperty() must be wrong as it always has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the initial IF condition has to do this:

```
 <xsl:if test = "sectionImage != ''">
```

Which is how XSLT/Xpath checks if a XML tag is null. Then Eric Herlitz's solution can be used, or a dummy approach to just start assigning values without the secondary IF condition.